# Is it best practice to apply a constraint in all directions of a view in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` that appears as the following blueprint:

[image]

I have realized that not all of my `View` objects have a constraint in all directions. For instance, as you will see, the `RecyclerView` does not have a constraint at the top. A few of my `TextView` objects do not have top and bottom constraints either.

What risk does this pose when trying to scale on multiple devices? Is there a recommended best practice? Right now, for instance, I am concerned the top of the`RecyclerView` could "stretch" on a larger device, in the absence of a constraint. Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="110dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Polls Created"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Votes Given"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="167dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Votes Received"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight=".33"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="USER X Recent polls"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How about dividing the content area and RecyclerView into two areas, applying percent height to RecyclerView and using percent height and percent width for the widgets in the content area? The font size is only a branch to the dimens according to the resolution.

Comment: When you say into 2 areas, what do you mean? I thought one of the purposes of the `ConstraintLayout` was to eliminate nested views.

Comment: I agree with your thoughts. What I mean is not to separate them into two ViewGroups, but rather to apply the height of the RecyclerView to percent and the remaining upper area to the remaining percent value, as appropriate. In my experience, applying the percent attribute was much more flexible in many situations than setting the dimension to dp. I want to talk more deeply, but I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

Comment: Can you post sample code / xml for what you are referring to? I understand how to set the weight, but would I need to create a `FrameLayout` for the top section as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my habit. Percent dimension and guideline are used properly so as not to put margins directly. However, it is necessary to calculate percentages so that the widgets do not overlap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/topGl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".05" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/textViewTopGl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/topGl"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Polls Created"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".05"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textViewTopGl" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Votes Given"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Votes Received"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="USER X Recent polls"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTopGl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".53" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recyclerViewTopGl" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be scaling the way I had hoped. Do you have a recommended tutorial or course on this? It appears Guidelines have worked, but I do not fully understand

Comment: I uploaded my analysis on constraintlayout to my blog, but it is in Korean....
By taking advantage of the guideline and percent dimension, you can flexibly deploy it in almost any situation without manually setting up dp. Try to design your layout in a way that does not use as much dp dimension as possible.
ConstraintLayout has many useful properties that can be flexibly coped with in various situations such as dimensionRatio, percent dimension, and so on. Thanks.

Comment: SInce you have aspect 1:1 for image, can you set either constraintWidth_percent or constraintHeight_percent to .25 ?

Comment: yes. but I mistake and edited partial code of the imageview. After applying percent to height, apply app: layout_constraintDimensionRatio = "w, 1: 1" so that the width is drawn as large as the height would have.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can get away with few constraints, I think adding all the necessary constraints when building your layout. The constraints that anchor your views and ensure where they appear on the screen and their dimensions to be futur-proof.

For example if you have a left/start constraint and no right/end constraint, you will not be able to set the width of your view to `match_constaint` it will just look like if it was set to `wrap_content` and can even go off screen. You also will not be able to use chaining, ...

The layout editor will display a red explanation mark on the top right when you have missing constraints that prevent the layout from being rendered correctly on the device.

Answer (score 1):

Just a habit of mine.

If I have to define constraints on all of the 4 sides of my view item, either the `layout_height` or `layout_width` would be set as 0dp, which means `match_constraint` in the `ConstraintLayout`. What it can achieve is to resize the view item according to the constraint by 'stretching' the view to fill the available space.

For example, your `RecyclerView` can be defined as this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

When you change the screen size, you can see the `Recyclerview` can resize nicely.

Moreover, I would avoid defining the `layout_width` and `layout_height` directly in the XML. If you really need to do so, you may use `dimens.xml` and reference to it.

Comment: So in this case, you are indeed constraining it to the `TextView` above it, and then manually setting a marginTop?

Comment: not really, depending what you wanna achieve (cos i dont know your requirement). you can set constraint to either the textView or recyclerview.

Comment: I basically don't want it to become disproportional on larger screens. I am very confused in the Design tab when adding views and some "stretch," where others are held in place. For instance, my 3 chained TextViews are not moving

Comment: For instance, I am playing with the preview on different devices and it is not mimicking my original layout, it becomes completely disorganized relative to my original layout

Comment: so after remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"` in `textView7`. then use my recyclerview code. is it what you wanna get?

Comment: btw your textView3 and textView2 are not vertically constraint. I guess you can see the error message in android studio: This view is not constraint vertically.

Comment: I really do not know how to constrain them, I want them chained horizontally but not sure what that means vertically. I thought ConstraintLayout would be easy but it seems overly complex. I am checking on tablet devices and it is not scaling properly

Comment: @tccpg288 that means at least one of the TOP or BOTTOM sides should be constraint